# Mysql - Load data infile query for Particular Values

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a Java swing application with back end Database **MySQL** . I've a screen to upload my datas to the Database using the Query like

```sql
LOAD DATA local INFILE  'D:\\TEMP\\import\\jan_jun2013.txt' 
INTO TABLE slsdata 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'   
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Here the datas are like from January to June. But if i want to **skip any month data** or to **upload only a particular month** then how will i modify the above query ?

In my database table , the date column is **'SLDATE'**.

*The Same question i've asked in some other forum's, but i'm not able to get any suggestions there!*

Any suggestions please.?

Comment: how about using a trigger. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460389/conditionally-ignore-rows-load-data-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO there is no a perfect solution for such scenario but you can utilize `IGNORE` clause.

For example if you were to have an `auto_increment` id column in your table and you already have a row in it with a known id then your query to import only rows for february might look like this

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE  '/path/to/your/file.txt' IGNORE
INTO TABLE slsdata 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'   
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@sldate)
SET id = IF(MID(@sldate, 6, 2) = '02', NULL, 1), sldate = @sldate
```

What it does it reads values of sldate field in @slfield variable then in `SET` clause it checks whether it's february and if it is then assigns NULL to `id` column and if not then assigned predefined existing value `1` violating a `UNIQUE` constraint and `IGNORE` clause does exactly that it skips a row in such a case.

---

That being said I'd recommend another approach:

1. create a temporary staging table without any constraints
2. load whole file in it
3. do all necessary cleansing, validating against ref tables, transformations etc. on required subset of data (e.g. for particular month) utilizing all SQL capabilities
4. insert required subset of data from staging table into your factual table
5. truncate or drop staging table